# Hibernate query giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate

This simple query

```
session = com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSession();
Query q = session.createQuery("recNo from SongChanges");
```

giving this stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
```

if I do

```
session = com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSession();
Query q = session.createQuery("from SongChanges");
```

I dont get the error, but I only need the recNo

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot the select:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select sc.recNo from SongChanges sc");
```

Comment: I thought that wasn't needed for hsql

Comment: @ijabz the select clause (that means the word select and the fields that you want to select) is not needed. But then you have to start with "from" and you get the entity. If you want to select specific fields, then you have to put select.

Comment: Ah,okay thanks. Where I think hibernate falls down is that if there is a problem the error messages it generates are rarely very helpful.

Comment: I don't think it is unreasonable to expect that users have read the documentation, where this is covered.  Sure error messages could always be better, but to expect to just slap stuff together without ever having read docs and expect it to work is just not reasonable.

Comment: I have read documentation, in fact Ive invested and read a couple of books on Hibernate, doesnt mean I'm not allowed to make mistakes in my code. The quality if error messages in hibernate is consistently poorer than any other mature library that I use.

Comment: I am getting this exception for ctx.getSession().createQuery("Truncate MyTable").executeUpdate();

Comment: @Jerry Hibernate uses HQL, not SQL. Try using [createSQLQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-) or [createNativeQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-), depending of the version of Hibernate you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This error also commonly happens when you use the method `createQuery` to run a named query, instead of `getNamedQuery`, for example:

```
session.createQuery("InvoiceItem.itemsFromInvoice")
```

when the correct approach would be

```
session.getNamedQuery("InvoiceItem.itemsFromInvoice")
```

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT clause provides more control over the result set than the from clause. If you want to obtain few properties of objects instead of the complete object, use the SELECT clause. Following is the simple syntax of using SELECT clause to get just name field of the Employee object:

```
String hql = "SELECT E.name FROM Employee E";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

If you want whole object that time "select * from" is not needed.